# Sensenet API: Best Way to Create Folder structure

Tags: task, sensenet

I want upload content to a specific path on sensenet. This path may not be already created on sensenet. So if the path do not exists, the system has to create it.

Using the Client API of Sensenet, the method available to create content runs Asynchronous. I tried to force it to run Synchronous but it seems not to happen, becaus sometimes the second folder is not created...

Here's a sample code:

```
private async Task CreateFolder(String parentPath, String folderName){
 var folder = Content.CreateNew(parentPath, "Folder", folderName);
 await folder.SaveAsync();
}

CreateFolder("/Root/Sites/Test/DocumentWorkSpace", "folder").Wait();
CreateFolder("/Root/Sites/Test/DocumentWorkSpace/folder", "subfolder").Wait();
```

I can use Tools.EnsurePathAsync(path) to create folder structure. But after this, I want to upload the file... (I'm having the same problem of the folder structure reported above.)

```
Task.Run(() => Tools.EnsurePathAsync(pathDocType)).Wait();

Task.Run(() =>{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteContent);
    Content.UploadAsync(pathDocType, "test.doc", stream).WaitAndUnwrapException();
    stream.Dispose();
}).Wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, depending on your use case.

### Importing a whole folder structure

Take a look at the import api in the client library. It is actually a single method that you can use to import a folder structure from the file system. It handles all folder creation and upload internally:

```cs
await Importer.ImportAsync(sourcePath, targetPath, options);
```

The options object can be used to customize the behavior of the algorithm (e.g. max degree of parallelism for large structures, defining a custom container type instead of the default Folder or defining an optional logging delegate method).

This method is scalable, meaning it is capable of importing a huge number of folders and files efficiently. It will return after importing every folder and file (filtered by the optional filters in the options parameter).

### Ensuring a parent folder chain

There is a single method for creating parent folders (if they do not exist yet).

```cs
await Tools.EnsurePathAsync(path);
```

You can call this with a non-existing path (e.g. /Root/Folder1/Folder2) and it will create it for you. This method only deals with folders, it has nothing to do with files.

Comment: Tools.EnsurePathAsync(path); works perfectly. The problem now is when I upload the file after creating the folder structure...
How can I grantee that the upload of the file is made after the creation of folder structure?
(I updated the question)